# Reactjs filter array

Tags: reactjs, filter

I am having an issue combining search filter and multi checkbox filter..

So this is my data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userType": "freelancer",
    "firstName": "Miss Beulah Crist DDS",
    "lastName": "Mr. Magnus Rau",
    "username": "towne.lizeth",
    "email": "zakary.roob@example.com",
    "email_verified_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
    "phone": "+1-860-422-5622",
    "two_factor_secret": null,
    "two_factor_recovery_codes": null,
    "created_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
    "user_avatar": "https://i.pravatar.cc/400",
    "user_full_name": "Miss Beulah Crist DDS Mr. Magnus Rau",
    "profile": {
      "id": 1,
      "gender": "male",
      "trade_name": "Fugiat dolorem praesentium veritatis aperiam.",
      "dob": null,
      "country": "American Samoa",
      "region": "Najran",
      "city": "Makkah",
      "about": "Et dolorem quod aperiam quia dicta voluptatibus. Iure aliquid ad exercitationem nesciunt ullam. Fugit animi doloremque quis ex officiis. Nisi quia qui sunt a earum earum.",
      "user_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
      "specialization_id": 30,
      "skills": null,
      "specialization": {
        "id": 30,
        "value": "المغنيين",
        "label": "المغنيين",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "created_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z"
      }
    },
    "media": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userType": "freelancer",
    "firstName": "Mr. Dawson Jacobi III",
    "lastName": "Taya Abbott",
    "username": "korey.hayes",
    "email": "hirthe.nick@example.com",
    "email_verified_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
    "phone": "+1-305-359-5353",
    "two_factor_secret": null,
    "two_factor_recovery_codes": null,
    "created_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
    "user_avatar": "https://i.pravatar.cc/400",
    "user_full_name": "Mr. Dawson Jacobi III Taya Abbott",
    "profile": {
      "id": 2,
      "gender": "female",
      "trade_name": "Ipsam maxime consequuntur in occaecati vel ipsa.",
      "dob": null,
      "country": "Antigua and Barbuda",
      "region": "Qassim",
      "city": "Khobar",
      "about": "Sequi hic assumenda error molestiae. Pariatur est sed neque. Accusantium nam quidem commodi cupiditate non voluptatem doloribus velit. Optio voluptatem deserunt consequuntur voluptatem iusto.",
      "user_id": 2,
      "created_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
      "specialization_id": 6,
      "skills": null,
      "specialization": {
        "id": 6,
        "value": "المصور ومرافق التصوير",
        "label": "المصور ومرافق التصوير",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "created_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-13T02:59:23.000000Z"
      }
    },
    "media": []
  },

]
```

So, I want to filter the users by their specialization using a checkboxes.

this is where I set the check-boxes values

```
 const handleCheckbox = (event, specialization) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            setCheckboxValues([
                ...checkboxValues,
                event.target.value
            ])
        } else {
            setCheckboxValues(checkboxValues.filter((value) => value !== specialization));
        }
    };
```

and this is where I filter the users using useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
        if (checkboxValues.length > 0) {
            console.log('currnet checkbox', checkboxValues)
            const newFreelancers = freelancers.filter(freelancer => {
                console.log('currnet value', freelancer.profile.specialization.value)
                return checkboxValues.includes(freelancer.profile.specialization.value)
            });
            // const newFreelancers = freelancers.filter(freelancer => freelancer.profile.specialization.value.includes(checkboxValues));
            setFreelancers(newFreelancers);
        } else {
            setFreelancers(initialFreelancers);
        }
    }, [checkboxValues])
```

The problem is when I check multi values it onley return one item from the array.

The whole code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import Skeleton from 'react-loading-skeleton';
import 'react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css';


export default function SearchFreelancers(props) {
    const [freelancers, setFreelancers] = useState(null);
    const [initialFreelancers, setInitialFreelancers] = useState(null);
    const [specializations, setSpecializations] = useState(null);
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
    const [checkboxValues, setCheckboxValues] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('api/specializations').then(response => {
            setSpecializations(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('api/freelnacers').then(response => {
            setFreelancers(response.data);
            setInitialFreelancers(response.data);
            // console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }, []);


    const handleChange = value => {
        let lowerCasedValue = value.toLowerCase();
        setSearchInput(lowerCasedValue);
    };


    const getFilterdFreelancers = () => {
        if (!searchInput) return freelancers;

        return freelancers.filter(freelancer => freelancer.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput)
            || freelancer.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput)
        );
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (checkboxValues.length > 0) {
            console.log('currnet checkbox', checkboxValues)
            const newFreelancers = freelancers.filter(freelancer => {
                // console.log('currnet value', freelancer.profile.specialization.value)
                // console.log('currnet freelancers', freelancer)
                return checkboxValues.includes(freelancer.profile.specialization.value)
            });
            // const newFreelancers = freelancers.filter(freelancer => freelancer.profile.specialization.value.includes(checkboxValues));
            setFreelancers(newFreelancers);
        } else {
            setFreelancers(initialFreelancers);
        }
    }, [checkboxValues])



    const filteredFreelancers = getFilterdFreelancers()


    const handleCheckbox = (event, specialization) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            console.log('event: ', event);
            console.log('value: ', event.target.value);
            setCheckboxValues([
                ...checkboxValues,
                event.target.value
            ])
        } else {
            setCheckboxValues(checkboxValues.filter((value) => value !== specialization));
        }
    };


    return (
        <div className="bg-[#F0F0F0]">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-4 p-4">
                <h1 className="font-smeibold text-xl text-gray-800">ابحث عن المبدع المناسب</h1>
                <select name="" id=""
                    className="block p-2 pl-10 text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500">
                    <option value="">فرز حسب</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4  p-4">
                <div className="mt-8">
                    <div className="relative mt-4">
                        <div className="flex absolute inset-y-0 left-0 items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" fill="none"
                                stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2"
                                    d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="default-search"
                            className="block p-4  w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 "
                            value={searchInput}
                            onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value)}
                            placeholder="أكتب ماتريد البحث عنه..."
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-3 mr-1">
                        <h1 className="text-xl text-gray-800">المجال</h1>
                        {specializations && specializations.map((specialization, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index} className="flex items-center mb-4 mt-2">
                                    <input
                                        id={specialization.value}
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        value={specialization.value}
                                        onChange={event => handleCheckbox(event, specialization.value)}
                                        className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 rounded border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500" />
                                    <label htmlFor={specialization.value} className="mr-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                                        {specialization.label}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>

                {filteredFreelancers === null || filteredFreelancers === undefined ?
                    <div className='col-span-2 mt-8'>
                        <Skeleton count={30} />
                    </div>
                    :
                    <div className="col-span-2 mt-8">
                        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-2">
                            {filteredFreelancers.map((freelnacer, index) => (
                                <div key={index} className=" flex flex-col items-center  bg-white p-4  shadow-sm rounded-xl mt-2 mb-20">
                                    <div className="-mt-16">
                                        <img className="w-28 h-28 shadow-md rounded-xl" src={freelnacer.user_avatar}
                                            alt="image" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between text-center  h-full">
                                        <div className="">
                                            <h2 className="text-md text-center font-bold text-gray-800 mt-2">{freelnacer.user_full_name}</h2>
                                            <p className="text-sm text-gray-600 mt-1">
                                                {freelnacer.profile.specialization.label}
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className=" w-full mt-6 mb-4">
                                            <a href={props.url + `/u/${freelnacer.username}`}
                                                className="bg-white text-[#6F3F70] border border-[#6F3F70] px-8 py-2 rounded-full hover:bg-[#6F3F70] hover:text-white transition-all">
                                                الملف
                                                الشخصي
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

if (document.getElementById('SearchFreelancers')) {
    const props = Object.assign({}, document.getElementById('SearchFreelancers').dataset)
    createRoot(document.getElementById('SearchFreelancers')).render(<SearchFreelancers {...props} />);
}
```

Comment: post `checkboxValues` values

Comment: Thanks, @SachilaRanawaka
```
currnet checkbox 
Array [ "فنانين المكياج", "المصور ومرافق التصوير" ]
```

Comment: there is no record with specification value `فنانين المكياج`. hence returning only one record

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Yeah I know I am just giving you an example!

Comment: logic seems to work fine. when do you get only one item

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka, What I want when I select فنانين المكياج or المغنين return both users, when I select only المغنين returns only that user who has this.

Comment: But there is no specification value for `فنانين المكياج` in your given dataset

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka, So I noticed when I select an option it works fine return the selected option. but when I select multi options it only return the users with the first selected option.

Comment: show element for `handleCheckbox` with the event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249544/discussion-between-tea-dev-and-sachila-ranawaka).

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka 
     <input
                            type="text"
                            id="default-search"
                            className="block p-4  w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 "
                            value={searchInput}
                            onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value)}
                            placeholder="أكتب ماتريد البحث عنه..."
                            required
                        />

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I added the whole code above.